# Writing a list into a text file

Tags: python, list, file

Using windows 10

Here's a sample of my code, where the problem is:

```
if choice2 == "d":
    amount = int(raw_input("How much money would you like to deposit? Current balance: %i : " % intBalance))
    newBalance = intBalance + amount

    print "Current balance: %i" %newBalance

    f.close()
    os.remove("accounts.txt")
    f = open("accounts.txt", "a+")

    fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[2])
    fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[1])
    fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[0])

    f.write(accessedAccount[0] + "\n")
    f.write(accessedAccount[1] + "\n")

    newBalance = str(newBalance)
    f.write(newBalance + "\n")

    for item in fileVar:
        f.write("%s\n" %item)
        test = raw_input("Waiting for input")
```

At the bottom is the code that writes the information of the list (called fileVar) into the text file (called f). It does write the information to the list but it messes up the order of the lines which cannot happen with the program I am making because the file must be able to be read back to the program to work later on.

Here is my entire code for context:

```
import os
import string

again = "y"
f = open('accounts.txt', 'a+')

fileVar = f.read().splitlines()
print fileVar
accessedAccount = []
data = f.read()

choice = raw_input("What would you like to do? (add/remove a bank account, access a bank account): ")

if choice == "a":
    while again == "y":
        accName = raw_input("Account owner's name: ")
        accType = raw_input("Account type: ")
        accBal = "0"

        f.seek(0, 2)
        f.write(accName + "\n")
        f.write(accType + "\n")
        f.write(accBal)
        f.write("\n")

        again = raw_input("Add another account?: ")

if choice == "a2":
    account = raw_input("What is the name of the account you wish to access?: ")
    for i, line in enumerate(fileVar):
        if account in line:
            for j in fileVar[i:i+3]:
                print j
                accessedAccount.append(j)
    print accessedAccount
    balance = accessedAccount[2]
    intBalance = int(balance)
    print accessedAccount

    choice2 = raw_input("This is your bank account. What would you like to do now? (Withdraw/deposit, exit): ")

    if choice2 == "d":
        amount = int(raw_input("How much money would you like to deposit? Current balance: %i : " %intBalance))
        newBalance = intBalance + amount
        print "Current balance: %i" %newBalance
        f.close()
        os.remove("accounts.txt")
        f = open ("accounts.txt", "a+")
        fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[2])
        fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[1])
        fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[0])
        f.write(accessedAccount[0] + "\n")
        f.write(accessedAccount[1] + "\n")
        newBalance = str(newBalance)
        f.write(newBalance + "\n")
        for item in fileVar:
            f.write("%s\n" %item)
            test = raw_input("Waiting for input")

    if choice2 == "w":
        amount = int(raw_input("How much money would you like to withdraw? Current balanace: %i : " %intBalance))
        newBalance = intBalance - amount
        print "Current Balance: %i" %newBalance
        f.close()
        os.remove("accounts.txt")
        f = open ("accounts.txt", "a+")
        fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[0])
        fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[1])
        fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[2])
        f.write(accessedAccount[0] + "\n")
        f.write(accessedAccount[1] + "\n")
        newBalance = str(newBalance)
        f.write(newBalance + "\n")
        for item in fileVar:
            f.write("%s\n" %item)
            test = raw_input("Waiting for input")

if choice == "r":
    removeChoice = raw_input("What is the name of the account you wish to remove?: ")
    f.close()
    os.remove("accounts.txt")
    f= open("accounts.txt", "a+")
    for i, line in enumerate(fileVar):
        if removeChoice in line:
            for j in fileVar[i:i+3]:
                accessedAccount.append(j)
    fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[0])
    fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[1])
    fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[2])
    for item in fileVar:
        f.write("%s\n" %item)

f.close()
```

for example, the original text file looks like this:

```
Ryan
Savings
0
John
Chequings
0
Carly
Savings
0
```

when it is re-written with edited information, what it is supposed to look like, if 300 dollars were added to Carly's account:

```
Carly
Savings
300
Ryan
Savings
0
John
Chequings
0
```

What it looks like instead:

```
Carly
Savings
300
John
Chequings
Ryan
0
Savings
0
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: correct the indentation if you plan anyone to help you :)

Comment: @MarkoMackic Oops sorry, should be all fixed now

Comment: you have various sections labeled `#Withdraw function` etc, why are they not actual functions?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen They were comments to remind me to make them into functions later on to clean up the code after I got everything functioning. Edited to remove those

Comment: ah, `fileVar.remove` will remove the first occurence of a value, so removing `Checking` may take it from a different line in the file, instead of removing them why not modify in place? you already know the three lines are `fileVar[i] , fileVar[i+1], fileVar[i+2]` (or at least if you keep a reference by breaking out of the outer loop)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I thought about that and tried to do that for about 2 days however I wasn't able to figure out a way to set the proper value for i, because the amount of accounts in the file will vary. If you know could you let me know please? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but some pointers which may end up making it much easier for both yourself and others to debug your code.

1) Functions are your friend. See if you can take small tasks and break them up into functions. For example, writing out someone's balance to a file could be a small function, which you might call like:

```
def write_balance_to_file(account_details):
     ...function code goes here...


account_details = {name:"Ryan", account:"Savings", balance:1000}
write_balance_to_file(account_details)
```

Opening and closing the file should be handled within that function, and preferably using:

```
with open('filename', 'a+') as f:
    f.write("A thing to write")
```

Note that you don't need to close the file manually when doing this.

2) Use a dictionary for storing a person's account details, rather than a list. Multiple accounts can be stored as a list of dictionaries. This makes it a lot easier to read as call such as:

```
f.write(accessedAccount[0] + "\n")
```

which becomes:

```
f.write(accessedAccount['name'] + '\n')
```

You can then pass in this dictionary to the `write_balance_to_file` method you will create. :)

3) Consider a tab-separated format for your `accounts.txt` file. Remember to escape/remove any tabs in your user input. This way each account will be on one line.

4) Possibly a little way in the future for you, but be aware that unit-testing exists, and is good practice. In essence, you can write tests (usually using a test framework such as py.test) which test each function/class/module under different input conditions. Anything that you can't break up into small, testable code fragments (functions or classes) is probably not good code. Writing tests is a great way to identify bugs in your code, and often helps to clarify your thinking. ALWAYS TEST!

Answer (score 0):

For a minimal change that will solve the issue, this is the code that needs to change:

```
for i, line in enumerate(fileVar):
    if account in line:
        for j in fileVar[i:i+3]:
            print j
            accessedAccount.append(j)
```

This records which entries are part of the `accessedAccount` however later on you just remove the first occurence of these entries:

```
    fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[2])
    fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[1])
    fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[0])
```

but if the entry is something as simple as `0` then it will not necessarily remove it from the correct place, so instead `pop` the accessed account out of the `fileVar` when putting them into `accessedAccount`:

```
for i, line in enumerate(fileVar):
    if account in line:
        for j in range(3):
            print i+j
            accessedAccount.append(fileVar.pop(i+j))
        #break # you probably want to stop checking by this point
```

This will remove the relevent lines from `fileVar` and put them in `accessedAccount` so the order of lines will not be messed up by using `.remove`, and then obviously comment out the calls to `.remove`:

```
##        fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[2])
##        fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[1])
##        fileVar.remove(accessedAccount[0])
```

This should fix the immediate problem of taking out the wrong lines.